# Observable concat method on array returns the same array

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, observable, rxjs5

In my service I try to solve the next problem. I have a json file with the names of other json files (cards):

```
{
  "filename1" : ... ,
  "filename2" : ... ,
  ...
  "filenameN" : ...
}
```

I need to load all that files. "filenameX" files have some card data :

```
{
  dataX
}
```

I need to combine loaded data in object:

```
{
  "filename1" : { data1 },
  "filename2" : { data2 },
...
  "filenameN" : { dataN }
}
```

I create Observer for any file loading and try to combine them to a high-level single Observer which is resolved when all corresponding Observers are. Here is my code:

```
import { Observable } from "rxjs/Observable";
import "rxjs/add/observable/concat";
import "rxjs/add/operator/map";
...
    _loadCards(dir, cardsListFile) {
        var http = ...
        var url = ...
        return Observable.create(function (observer) {
            http.get(url + dir + "/" + cardsListFile + ".json").map(res => { return res.json(); }).subscribe(list => {
                let data = {};
                let observers = [];
                for(var card in list) {
                    if(list.hasOwnProperty(card)) {
                        let obs = http.get(url + dir + "/cards/" + card + ".json").map(res => { return res.json(); });
                        observers.push(obs);
                        let getData = function(card) {
                            obs.subscribe(cardData => {
                                data[card] = cardData;
                            });
                        };
                        getData(card);
                    }
                }

                let concatResult = Observable.concat(observers);
                console.log(concatResult);
                concatResult.subscribe(result => {
                    observer.onNext(data);
                    observer.onCompleted();
                });         
            });
        });
    };
```

However, concat operator of Observer doesn't work as described - it returns the same array of Observers as its input. Where is the problem and what other operators can I use to make my solution more straight forward (because now it's defenitely ugly)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JSBIN with solution: http://jsbin.com/dahaqif/edit?js,console

I'm assuming you have two observables, one to get the list of filenames, the other to get the data for a specific filename:

```ts
const filenamesObs = Observable.of({
  "filename1" : null,
  "filename2" : null,
  "filename3" : null
});
// This is actually a function that returns an observable.
const filedataObs = (filename) => {
  return Observable.of(`This is the data for ${filename}`);
}
```

Now, here's how you can combine the two observables to obtain the data structure you described:

```ts
const source = filenamesObs

  // Extract the list of filenames as an array.
  .map(obj => Object.keys(obj))

  // Flatten the array, i.e. emit each filename individually
  // vs a SINGLE array containing ALL filenames.
  .mergeMap(val => val)

  // Get the data for each filename.
  .mergeMap(filename =>
    filedataObs(filename).map(data => Object.assign({}, { filename: filename, data: data }))
  )

  // At this point, you have a stream of { filename, data } objects.
  // Reduce everything back to a single object.
  .reduce((acc, curr) => {
    acc[curr.filename] = curr.data;
    return acc;
  }, {});
```

If you subscribe and log the result to the console, you'll see:

```
[Object] {
  filename1: "This is the data for filename1",
  filename2: "This is the data for filename2",
  filename3: "This is the data for filename3"
}
```

**Additional clarifications following Arseniy's comment**

- The first `mergeMap()` is a "trick" to transform the SINGLE array of values we have at the beginning into MULTIPLE, INDIVIDUAL values. Since you want to be able to process each filename individually (to fetch the corresponding data), it's more convenient to receive the filenames one by one vs as a big array containing all filenames. To make it crystal clear, you should go to my JSBIN and add the line `.do(console.log)` **before** and **after** the first `mergeMap()`. You'll immediately understand the difference.
- The second `mergeMap()` "projects" the values of a source observable into a target observable. It sounds fancy but it simply means we are transforming the filenames (1st observable) into HTTP requests to get the files' data (2nd observable).
- Finally, `Object.assign()` lets met put everything back together. Since we have data coming from two observables — the one emitting the filenames and the one emitting the file data — we need to merge everything into a single container before we can use it (or transform it further). For this I'm using `Object.assign()` to create a temporary object with two properties, `filename` and `data`. Note that is vanilla JavaScript, it has nothing to do with observables. Again, you can add a `.do(console.log)` line after the second `mergeMap()` to print out to the console what the stream contains at this point.

Comment: Thank you, especially for providing comments on every step. I still need to understand some points as several mergeMaps and why do you use Object.assign. I've decided your solution is the best one. The only thing I had to add was manual pointing type: reduce<{ filename?: string, data?: Object }> for compiler to pass.

Comment: You're welcome. I have amended my answer to clarify my code and hopefully reply to the questions you just asked.

Comment: As for mergeMap, I understood why it is used the first time from the first your comment. The problem is to understand what this method is really intended for, how usually to use it and why it is called "mergeMap" and not "divideMap", because official doc on it is a hell

Comment: I understand now logic of using Object.assign(), as I expected we can create temp object as usual, but it requires additional braces: "data => { return { filename: filename, data: data }}" What to use is just a matter of choice

Comment: Thank you for additional clarifications. I still need a lot of time to understand how mergeMap works and when to use it.

Comment: Oh yeah. It took me a while to understand RxJS, too. The site https://www.learnrxjs.io/ is a good resource, with code examples for all major RxJS 5 operators. Also, the site egghead.io has [several (paid) courses about RxJS](https://egghead.io/technologies/rx).

Answer (score 1):

Rule #1: **Never** use custom subscriptions inside other subscriptions - there is maybe 0.1% of cases where this is really needed.

I've rewritten your stream a little how it could be done:

```
_loadCards(dir, cardsListFile) {
    var http = ...
    var url = ...
    return http.get(url + dir + "/" + cardsListFile + ".json")
        .map(res => res.json())
        .switchMap(fileMap => Rx.Observable.from(Object.keys(fileMap)))
        .concatMap(card => http.get(url + dir + "/cards/" + card + ".json")
               .map(res => ({[card]: res.json()})))
        .map(arrayOfCardResultObjects => Object.assign.apply({}, arrayOfCardResultObjects));
};
```

---

An adjusted version of this to run live as a snippet:

```js
getMockedCardMap()
    .switchMap(fileMap => Rx.Observable.from(Object.keys(fileMap)))
    .concatMap(card => getMockedCardFromFile(card).map(res => ({[card]: res})))
    .toArray()
    .map(arrayOfCardResultObjects => Object.assign.apply({}, arrayOfCardResultObjects))
    .subscribe(console.log);


// Mocked helper-methods
function getMockedCardMap() {
    return Rx.Observable.of({
        "file1": "foo",
        "file2": "bar",
        "file3": "baz"
    });
}

function getMockedCardFromFile(file) {
    return Rx.Observable.of("Result from: " + file);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/rxjs/bundles/Rx.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Like I said to @martin, why use `for` loops? RxJS includes looping operators already. You can keep chaining operators starting from the original observable until you reach the desired result, thus avoiding the temporary `cards$` variable.

Comment: Good point - I misread the provided example and thought the file-path was in the value, not the key - I've adjusted the code

Comment: Thank you for your solution, I'll test it as an accepted one. As I understand async and functional programming, there really should not be used subscriptions inside subscriptions and for loops. However, since I'm very bad at functional programming and also Observers is a new concept for me, I can't create such solutions on my own, just understand that mine are bad.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not completely sure I understand what you want to do but the [`concat()`](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#instance-method-concat) operator takes its parameters unpacked and not as an array.

This means that `Observable.concat(observables)` will just reemit the Observables as they are in the `observables` array.

What you want instead is pass the array unpacked `Observable.concat(...observables)` which is the same as:

```
Observable.concat(observable1, observable2, observable3 ,...)
```

I think this simulates what you're trying to do. It's uses `forkJoin` instead of `concat` so it waits until all of the Observables complete.

```
var input = {
  "filename1": 'data1',
  "filename2": 'data2',
  "filenameN": 'dataN'
};

let keys = Object.keys(input);

let observables = keys.map(key => {
  return Observable.of(input[key]).map(s => s.split("").reverse().join(""));
});

Observable.forkJoin(observables, (...results) => {
    let combined = {};
    keys.forEach((key, i) => {
      combined[key] = results[i];
    });
    return combined;
  })
  .subscribe(val => console.log(val));
```

This prints to console:

```
{ filename1: '1atad', filename2: '2atad', filenameN: 'Natad' }
```

See live demo: https://jsbin.com/coruyu/4/edit?js,console

Comment: Why use `forEach` and `for` loops? RxJS includes looping operators already. The final code looks cleaner when you stay in RxJS syntax rather than alternate between RxJS and JS syntax. Also, you don't need a temporary variable to store a list of observables (`observables`), you can keep chaining operators starting from the original observable until you reach the desired result. (See my answer.)

Comment: Because that's what the result selector function in `forkJoin` is made for. I'm using `observables` array because that's how the OP is doing it and I can't know what exactly is his use-case and why is he doing it this way. If you think using `.map().mergeMap().mergeMap().reduce()` and then yet another `map()` inside `mergeMap()` is easier to understand... well I'm sorry for anyone refactoring this code.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't mean to upset you. Just trying constructive conversation so we can all learn something. :)

Comment: Thank you for clearing how to use Observable.concat(...observables), I really didn't know about such language construction. I agree that patterns like map->mergemap->mergemap->reduce are very difficult to understand   for someone who is not using functional programming every day. For example, I spent about half an hour on understanding AngularFrance's solution and still need to clear some moments. However I also understand that libraries that use FP a lot like ReactiveX are intended and optimized for such code.